# Vertical layout issue with 2 UILabels inside a StackView

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell, uistackview

I have a title label as defined below:

```
private lazy var titleLabel: UILabel = {
 let label = UILabel()
 label.numberOfLines = 2
 label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.init(rawValue: 999), for: .vertical)
 return label
}()

private lazy var descriptionLabel: UILabel = {
  let label = UILabel()
  label.numberOfLines = 0
  label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
  return label
}()
```

`titleLabel` can grow and force to shrink the `descriptionLabel`. 
The cell is height is fixed to 120 or 78. When the cell height is 78, the `descriptionLabel` height is `0`

Both are added to a `UIStackview`

```
private lazy var labelStackView: UIStackView = {
  let stackView = UIStackView()
  stackView.addArrangedSubview(titleLabel)
  stackView.addArrangedSubview(descriptionLabel)
  stackView.axis = .vertical
  stackView.distribution = .fill
  return stackView
}()
```

The stackView is added inside the `containerView` with padding to the top, left, right & bottom. The `containerView` is pinned to the edges of the `contentView`.

The `distribution` on the `stackView` is set to `fill` to allow `descriptionLabel` to shrink. This set up causes the constraint to break.

**Issue**

`titleLabel` - Height is ambiguous for UILabel

`descriptionLabel` - Height and vertical position are ambiguous for UILabel

Is there a way to achieve this without breaking the constraint?

I tried setting content resistance priority for both labels as follows:

`titleLabel` -> `label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.init(rawValue: 999), for: .vertical)`

`descriptionLabel` -> `label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.init(rawValue: 998), for: .vertical)`

I still had no luck.

Answer (score 10):

By setting a content hugging priority on the `descriptionLabel`, I was able to fix the layout ambiguity.

```
private lazy var descriptionLabel: UILabel = {
 let label = UILabel()
 label.numberOfLines = 0
 label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
 label.setContentHuggingPriority(.high, for: .vertical)
 return label
}()
```